# Something wrong with search tokens?

Tags: support, search

I tried a simple search: **[c++] string "long long"**. I didn't find the question I was looking for, until I used Google and got to [convert string to long long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303759/convert-string-to-long-long).

I paid more attention to the search results page, and found out that I was getting ['search results for posts containing **"long long"** tagged with **c++ string**'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2b%2b%5D%20string%20long%20long)

So it looks like *string* is considered as if enclosed between square brackets even though it isn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behavior is [documented on the advanced search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

> Results are weighted heavily towards question title matches, **and any search terms matching the most popular 60 tags will be automatically mapped to a tag to help narrow your search.**

[string](/questions/tagged/string) is currently the 39th most popular tag on Stack Overflow, so that's why it's getting treated as a tag. You can [add quotation marks around the word](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+%22string%22+%22long+long%22) to override this behavior.

```
[c++] "string" "long long"
```

Comment: Thanks. I had read the faq's answer on search but didn't get to the advance search page. No reference to quotation for overridding though.

Comment: @AntonioPérez I'm not sure if it's documented anywhere, or if I got it from Google, where adding quotation marks also prevents uncommon words from getting "corrected" in your query.